# yacc token header file not being generated by yacc in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, yacc

I may be mis-diagnosing this, but when I compile my flex/bison project in Xcode, it doesn't appear to update the header file that contains the tokens, in my case `parser.h`. I added a new token in my .y but it's not showing up in my .l

Normally occurs if you specify the `-d` flag in yacc/bison. I thought this would be on by default, but to be sure I added the -d to 'other yacc flags' setting in the target's build settings, but that and it didn't seem to have any effect.

I also suspected it might be generating a parser.tab.h, but that's not happening either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is that XCode invokes `bison` with the `-y` flag (perhaps using the `yacc` command) with the result that the header file is named `y.tab.h`, to be compatible with old yacc-based compile scripts.

Using "yacc" mode is not recommended; it should only be used when necessary to process legacy source code. So it's worth trying to figure out how to get XCode to not use the `-y` flag.

Comment: Ah! You nailed it. I didn't notice this because it hides the resulting file in a build folder Waaaayyyy down the directory chain. Searching on that name revealed it. Ok, now I have a direction to look in, thanks!